# Why am I getting an undefined reference in this code?

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, undefined-reference, glew

I'm using Windows and I'm calling the function `glGenBuffers`. When I use it I get the following error:

```
error: undefined reference to _imp____glewBufferData
```

I'm linking against the `glew32` dll that is in my `MinGW/lib` folder, and I have `glew.h` inside `MinGW/include`. I also put the `glew32.dll` inside the `WINDOWS/system32` folder.

I'm compiling like this:

```
mingw32-g++.exe ... -lglfw -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglew32 -lgdi32 -lglu32 -lglew32s
```

Is it the order of the libraries that's causing the problem? If so, what should come before the other?

Comment: Add `-DGLEW_STATIC` to your commandline since you are linking to the static library. Your desription in the question is wrong, the GLEW32 DLL is not related to your program in any way shape or form. You can go ahead and delete it to save disk space :P

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I thought this was a dynamic library since I'm using a dll...

Comment: Nope, by linking to `glew32s` you are linking to the ***static*** library (that is what the **s** stands for). In fact, using mingw you cannot even link to the dynamic library without jumping through dozens of hoops. This error is coming up because you compiled at least one of your source files without defining `GLEW_STATIC`, so it is using the wrong linkage.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm also linking to the dynamic library (`glew32.dll`)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Okay, what you said was right. It worked. If you make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MinGW does not like the binary dynamic library that ships with glew for Windows, it will only work with Visual C++ unless you do a lot of unnecessarily complicated things to it.

The far simpler solution is to remove `-lglew32` from your build commandline, keep `-lglew32s` (static library) and add `-DGLEW_STATIC`. The last part is very important because glew assumes dynamic linkage by default when you `#include "glew.h"`. `GLEW_STATIC` must be defined first for the linker to properly resolve static symbols on Windows.

Comment: Could you help me with another problem? I created a new project and I got an undefined reference for using `glfwWindowHint`. So I started linking against `glfw3`. But then I got a whole bunch of multiple definition errors for a bunch of functions that I'm not even using. It only starts happening when I use `setWindowHint`. Any ideas?

Comment: @templateboy You would have to ask another question, or search for a similar one with an answer already. Unfortunately, I have never used glfw.